# Generate a value given three other values with caps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Given a Target $T$ whose value is a positive integer. And, given a $3$ integer tuple $(N_1,N_2,N_3)$ where the value of $N_1$ is $N_1$ times $2$; the value of $N_2$ is $N_2$ times $3$; and the value of *N3* is *N3* times *4* is there a simple way to work out all possible values for *N1*, *N2* and *N3* so that *T* = (*N1* *2)+(*N2* * 3)+(*N3* * 4).  Importantly *N1*, *N2* and *N3* have proscribed bounds that may be larger than the value of *T*. For example:

$T= 123$
$3$ int tuple = $(300, 3, 200) = 1409: (600+9+800)$

With this in mind, I'm seeking a way to generate all combinations of (N1, N2, N3) that will equal *T*. for example, where $T=123, (50, 1, 5) = 123 or (0, 1, 30) = 123$

**EDIT:** *N1*, *N2*, and *N3* must be whole numbers with a value of 0 or greater.

To add some further clarity, if solving this were being approached through code one method of solving would be as follows:

```
T = 123
my_tuple = (300,3,200)
good_combo = []

 for twos in range((my_tuple[1]), -1, -1):
            num_twos = twos*2
            for threes in range((my_tuple[2]), -1, -1):
                num_threes = threes * 3
                for fours in range((my_tuple[3]), -1, -1):
                    num_fours = fours * 4
                    combo = num_twos + num_threes + num_fours
                    if my_tuple == T:
                        good_combo.append((twos, threes, fours))
```

The problem with the above approach is that it is far too slow when you are dealing with large numbers.

Apologies if this is a really simply question. I'm trying to improve my maths.

Thanks for reading

Comment: "The value of $N_1$ is $N_1$ times $2$".  That is to say, $N_1=0$.

Comment: Please clarify that condition on $N_1, N_2$ and $N_3$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I've edited the question to hopefully better clarify with regards your comments. thanks.

Comment: @saulspatz I've edited the question to hopefully better clarify with regards your comments. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is wondering how N1=2N1 while I am wondering what N1, N2, N3 have proscribed bounds that may be larger than T means.

Basically you want $T=2N_1+3N_2+4N_3=2(N_1+2N_3)+3N_2$ with N being integers right? Well it might be easier to deal with an example so let's pick T=123 as you did. $N_2=\frac{123-2(N_1+2N_3)}{3}=41-\frac 2 3(N_1+2N_3)$.

The only way N2 can be an integer is if N1+2N3 is divisible by 3. So let $N_1+2N_3=3c,c\in\mathbb Z$. If N1, N2, N3 can be negative integers, there are infinitely many solutions. If they have to be positive or there are other restrictions, there could be finitely many solutions. Let's say that they all have to positive. Then $N_2=41-2c, c=20,19,...,-40,-41$. And $N_1+2N_3=3c$. For c=20, we have N1+2N3=60, so pairs are (0,30),(2,29), (4,28),...,(58,1), (60,0). For c=19, we have N1+2N3=57, so pairs are (1,28),(3,27),...,(57,0), and finally for c=-123 we have N1+2N3=-41. So we assumed N is positive so let's actually back up to um c=1. Then N1+2N3=3. So pairs are (1,1), (3,0). And for c=0, the pair is (0,0). So we've solved for all possibilities. They're

$$\begin{matrix}c&N_2&(N_1,N_3)\\
20&1&(0,30),(2,29), (4,28),...,(58,1), (60,0)\\
19&3&(1,28),(3,27),...,(57,0)\\
...\\
1&39&(1,1), (3,0)\\
0&41&(0,0)\end{matrix}$$

Let's see if one of them works, N1=3,N2=3,N3=27. We get 6+9+108=123.

Now for an algorithm, you surely know how to make an algorithm for this. Let's say N1 can be between -20 and 40, N2 can be between -30 and 50, N3 can be between -3 and 30. Try all the possibilities and select the ones that work.

```
N1=-20:40
N2=-30:50
N3=-3:30
T=123
oks=matrix(0, ncol=3, nrow=1)
for (i in N1) {
  for (j in N2) {
    for (k in N3) {
      if (2*i+3*j+4*k==T) {
        oks=rbind(oks, matrix(c(i,j,k), ncol=3))
      }
    }
  }
}
oks=oks[-1,]
```

Values that work

```
> head(oks)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -20   17   28
[2,]  -20   21   25
[3,]  -20   25   22
[4,]  -20   29   19
[5,]  -20   33   16
[6,]  -20   37   13
> tail(oks)
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[670,]   40   -3   13
[671,]   40    1   10
[672,]   40    5    7
[673,]   40    9    4
[674,]   40   13    1
[675,]   40   17   -2
> print(oks)
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]  -20   17   28
  [2,]  -20   21   25
  [3,]  -20   25   22
  [4,]  -20   29   19
  [5,]  -20   33   16
  [6,]  -20   37   13
  [7,]  -20   41   10
  [8,]  -20   45    7
  [9,]  -20   49    4
 [10,]  -19   15   29
 [11,]  -19   19   26
 [12,]  -19   23   23
 [13,]  -19   27   20
 [14,]  -19   31   17
 [15,]  -19   35   14
 [16,]  -19   39   11
 [17,]  -19   43    8
 [18,]  -19   47    5
 [19,]  -18   13   30
 [20,]  -18   17   27
 [21,]  -18   21   24
 [22,]  -18   25   21
 [23,]  -18   29   18
 [24,]  -18   33   15
 [25,]  -18   37   12
 [26,]  -18   41    9
 [27,]  -18   45    6
 [28,]  -18   49    3
 [29,]  -17   15   28
 [30,]  -17   19   25
 [31,]  -17   23   22
 [32,]  -17   27   19
 [33,]  -17   31   16
 [34,]  -17   35   13
 [35,]  -17   39   10
 [36,]  -17   43    7
 [37,]  -17   47    4
 [38,]  -16   13   29
 [39,]  -16   17   26
 [40,]  -16   21   23
 [41,]  -16   25   20
 [42,]  -16   29   17
 [43,]  -16   33   14
 [44,]  -16   37   11
 [45,]  -16   41    8
 [46,]  -16   45    5
 [47,]  -16   49    2
 [48,]  -15   11   30
 [49,]  -15   15   27
 [50,]  -15   19   24
 [51,]  -15   23   21
 [52,]  -15   27   18
 [53,]  -15   31   15
 [54,]  -15   35   12
 [55,]  -15   39    9
 [56,]  -15   43    6
 [57,]  -15   47    3
 [58,]  -14   13   28
 [59,]  -14   17   25
 [60,]  -14   21   22
 [61,]  -14   25   19
 [62,]  -14   29   16
 [63,]  -14   33   13
 [64,]  -14   37   10
 [65,]  -14   41    7
 [66,]  -14   45    4
 [67,]  -14   49    1
 [68,]  -13   11   29
 [69,]  -13   15   26
 [70,]  -13   19   23
 [71,]  -13   23   20
 [72,]  -13   27   17
 [73,]  -13   31   14
 [74,]  -13   35   11
 [75,]  -13   39    8
 [76,]  -13   43    5
 [77,]  -13   47    2
 [78,]  -12    9   30
 [79,]  -12   13   27
 [80,]  -12   17   24
 [81,]  -12   21   21
 [82,]  -12   25   18
 [83,]  -12   29   15
 [84,]  -12   33   12
 [85,]  -12   37    9
 [86,]  -12   41    6
 [87,]  -12   45    3
 [88,]  -12   49    0
 [89,]  -11   11   28
 [90,]  -11   15   25
 [91,]  -11   19   22
 [92,]  -11   23   19
 [93,]  -11   27   16
 [94,]  -11   31   13
 [95,]  -11   35   10
 [96,]  -11   39    7
 [97,]  -11   43    4
 [98,]  -11   47    1
 [99,]  -10    9   29
[100,]  -10   13   26
[101,]  -10   17   23
[102,]  -10   21   20
[103,]  -10   25   17
[104,]  -10   29   14
[105,]  -10   33   11
[106,]  -10   37    8
[107,]  -10   41    5
[108,]  -10   45    2
[109,]  -10   49   -1
[110,]   -9    7   30
[111,]   -9   11   27
[112,]   -9   15   24
[113,]   -9   19   21
[114,]   -9   23   18
[115,]   -9   27   15
[116,]   -9   31   12
[117,]   -9   35    9
[118,]   -9   39    6
[119,]   -9   43    3
[120,]   -9   47    0
[121,]   -8    9   28
[122,]   -8   13   25
[123,]   -8   17   22
[124,]   -8   21   19
[125,]   -8   25   16
[126,]   -8   29   13
[127,]   -8   33   10
[128,]   -8   37    7
[129,]   -8   41    4
[130,]   -8   45    1
[131,]   -8   49   -2
[132,]   -7    7   29
[133,]   -7   11   26
[134,]   -7   15   23
[135,]   -7   19   20
[136,]   -7   23   17
[137,]   -7   27   14
[138,]   -7   31   11
[139,]   -7   35    8
[140,]   -7   39    5
[141,]   -7   43    2
[142,]   -7   47   -1
[143,]   -6    5   30
[144,]   -6    9   27
[145,]   -6   13   24
[146,]   -6   17   21
[147,]   -6   21   18
[148,]   -6   25   15
[149,]   -6   29   12
[150,]   -6   33    9
[151,]   -6   37    6
[152,]   -6   41    3
[153,]   -6   45    0
[154,]   -6   49   -3
[155,]   -5    7   28
[156,]   -5   11   25
[157,]   -5   15   22
[158,]   -5   19   19
[159,]   -5   23   16
[160,]   -5   27   13
[161,]   -5   31   10
[162,]   -5   35    7
[163,]   -5   39    4
[164,]   -5   43    1
[165,]   -5   47   -2
[166,]   -4    5   29
[167,]   -4    9   26
[168,]   -4   13   23
[169,]   -4   17   20
[170,]   -4   21   17
[171,]   -4   25   14
[172,]   -4   29   11
[173,]   -4   33    8
[174,]   -4   37    5
[175,]   -4   41    2
[176,]   -4   45   -1
[177,]   -3    3   30
[178,]   -3    7   27
[179,]   -3   11   24
[180,]   -3   15   21
[181,]   -3   19   18
[182,]   -3   23   15
[183,]   -3   27   12
[184,]   -3   31    9
[185,]   -3   35    6
[186,]   -3   39    3
[187,]   -3   43    0
[188,]   -3   47   -3
[189,]   -2    5   28
[190,]   -2    9   25
[191,]   -2   13   22
[192,]   -2   17   19
[193,]   -2   21   16
[194,]   -2   25   13
[195,]   -2   29   10
[196,]   -2   33    7
[197,]   -2   37    4
[198,]   -2   41    1
[199,]   -2   45   -2
[200,]   -1    3   29
[201,]   -1    7   26
[202,]   -1   11   23
[203,]   -1   15   20
[204,]   -1   19   17
[205,]   -1   23   14
[206,]   -1   27   11
[207,]   -1   31    8
[208,]   -1   35    5
[209,]   -1   39    2
[210,]   -1   43   -1
[211,]    0    1   30
[212,]    0    5   27
[213,]    0    9   24
[214,]    0   13   21
[215,]    0   17   18
[216,]    0   21   15
[217,]    0   25   12
[218,]    0   29    9
[219,]    0   33    6
[220,]    0   37    3
[221,]    0   41    0
[222,]    0   45   -3
[223,]    1    3   28
[224,]    1    7   25
[225,]    1   11   22
[226,]    1   15   19
[227,]    1   19   16
[228,]    1   23   13
[229,]    1   27   10
[230,]    1   31    7
[231,]    1   35    4
[232,]    1   39    1
[233,]    1   43   -2
[234,]    2    1   29
[235,]    2    5   26
[236,]    2    9   23
[237,]    2   13   20
[238,]    2   17   17
[239,]    2   21   14
[240,]    2   25   11
[241,]    2   29    8
[242,]    2   33    5
[243,]    2   37    2
[244,]    2   41   -1
[245,]    3   -1   30
[246,]    3    3   27
[247,]    3    7   24
[248,]    3   11   21
[249,]    3   15   18
[250,]    3   19   15
[251,]    3   23   12
[252,]    3   27    9
[253,]    3   31    6
[254,]    3   35    3
[255,]    3   39    0
[256,]    3   43   -3
[257,]    4    1   28
[258,]    4    5   25
[259,]    4    9   22
[260,]    4   13   19
[261,]    4   17   16
[262,]    4   21   13
[263,]    4   25   10
[264,]    4   29    7
[265,]    4   33    4
[266,]    4   37    1
[267,]    4   41   -2
[268,]    5   -1   29
[269,]    5    3   26
[270,]    5    7   23
[271,]    5   11   20
[272,]    5   15   17
[273,]    5   19   14
[274,]    5   23   11
[275,]    5   27    8
[276,]    5   31    5
[277,]    5   35    2
[278,]    5   39   -1
[279,]    6   -3   30
[280,]    6    1   27
[281,]    6    5   24
[282,]    6    9   21
[283,]    6   13   18
[284,]    6   17   15
[285,]    6   21   12
[286,]    6   25    9
[287,]    6   29    6
[288,]    6   33    3
[289,]    6   37    0
[290,]    6   41   -3
[291,]    7   -1   28
[292,]    7    3   25
[293,]    7    7   22
[294,]    7   11   19
[295,]    7   15   16
[296,]    7   19   13
[297,]    7   23   10
[298,]    7   27    7
[299,]    7   31    4
[300,]    7   35    1
[301,]    7   39   -2
[302,]    8   -3   29
[303,]    8    1   26
[304,]    8    5   23
[305,]    8    9   20
[306,]    8   13   17
[307,]    8   17   14
[308,]    8   21   11
[309,]    8   25    8
[310,]    8   29    5
[311,]    8   33    2
[312,]    8   37   -1
[313,]    9   -5   30
[314,]    9   -1   27
[315,]    9    3   24
[316,]    9    7   21
[317,]    9   11   18
[318,]    9   15   15
[319,]    9   19   12
[320,]    9   23    9
[321,]    9   27    6
[322,]    9   31    3
[323,]    9   35    0
[324,]    9   39   -3
[325,]   10   -3   28
[326,]   10    1   25
[327,]   10    5   22
[328,]   10    9   19
[329,]   10   13   16
[330,]   10   17   13
[331,]   10   21   10
[332,]   10   25    7
[333,]   10   29    4
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 342 rows ]
```

Try one of them

```
> -10*2 +  41*3   + 5*4
[1] 123
```

### Update

```
T=123
my=c(300, 2, 200)
ans=matrix(0, ncol=3)
for (N1 in seq(max(0, (T-3*my[2]-4*my[3])/2), min(T/2, my[1]))) {
  for (N2 in seq(max(0, (T-2*N1-4*my[3])/3), min(my[2], (T-2*N1)/3))) {
    N3=T-2*N1-3*N2
    if (N3 %% 4 == 0) {
      ans=rbind(ans, matrix(c(N1, N2, N3/4), nrow=1))
    }
  }
}
ans=ans[-1,]
ans

for (k in 1:nrow(ans)) {
  print(ans[k,1]*2+ans[k,2]*3+ans[k,3]*4==T)
}

n=0
for (k in 0:my[1]) {
  for (j in 0:my[2]) {
    for (i in 0:my[3]) {
      if (k*2+j*3+i*4==T) n=n+1
    }
  }
}
print(n)
```

out

````
> ans
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    1   30
 [2,]    2    1   29
 [3,]    4    1   28
 [4,]    6    1   27
 [5,]    8    1   26
 [6,]   10    1   25
 [7,]   12    1   24
 [8,]   14    1   23
 [9,]   16    1   22
[10,]   18    1   21
[11,]   20    1   20
[12,]   22    1   19
[13,]   24    1   18
[14,]   26    1   17
[15,]   28    1   16
[16,]   30    1   15
[17,]   32    1   14
[18,]   34    1   13
[19,]   36    1   12
[20,]   38    1   11
[21,]   40    1   10
[22,]   42    1    9
[23,]   44    1    8
[24,]   46    1    7
[25,]   48    1    6
[26,]   50    1    5
[27,]   52    1    4
[28,]   54    1    3
[29,]   56    1    2
[30,]   58    1    1
[31,]   60    1    0

> for (k in 1:nrow(ans)) {
+   print(ans[k,1]*2+ans[k,2]*3+ans[k,3]*4==T)
+ }
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE

> print(n)
[1] 31
```
````

Comment: I've modified my question to better clarify what I mean. you're essentially correct about my Question. the Issue, which I should have originally stated is that if I take a nested four loop to solving it then its very slow on large numbers. Hence asking if there's a better mathematical approach.

Comment: @JMcK I did a for loop using just 2 loops and min max bounds. See if you like it.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks!